# List all posts in both categories (Jekyll / Liquid)

Tags: jekyll, liquid

**I need to list all of the posts that contain BOTH categories in a for loop.**

`{% assign cooking_pages = site.categories.cooking & site.categories.pictures %}`

Obviously the above doesn't work, but that's basically what I want to do.

I know I can do this:

`{% assign cooking_pages = site.categories.cooking | sort:"title"%}
  {% for post in cooking_pages %}
    {% if post.categories contains 'pictures' %}
         Do whatever I want to do
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}`

However my function uses loopindex and modulo, so the if statement messes things up. **Is there a way to select posts that exist in BOTH categories?**

Here is my actual code:

```
{% assign sorted_pages = (site.categories.2018 | sort:"date") | reverse %}
<table>{% for post in sorted_pages %}
  {% assign loopindex = forloop.index | modulo: 3 %}
  {% if loopindex == 1 %}
    <tr><td id="entries"><strong><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></strong></td>
  {% elsif loopindex == 0 %}
    <td id="entries"><strong><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></strong></td></tr>
  {% else %}
    <td id="entries"><strong><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></strong></td>
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}</table>
```

It gives me nice tables on this page: https://200wordrpg.github.io/2018entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a list filtered on two categories :

```
{% assign list = site.categories.cooking | where_exp: "post", "post.categories contains 'pictures'" %}
```

You can even chain multiple `where_exp` filters to filter on three, four or more categories.

Comment: @DavidJacquel Am I correct in understanding that the `where_exp` ADDS to the `list` array, it first getting the cooking posts and then the filter adding the picture posts? Rather than FILTERING the cooking posts as I thought it might operate? That is pretty cool if it does.

Comment: The `where_exp` only keep posts from `site.categories.cooking` that contains 'picture' category in their `categories` array. So it filters, it didn't add.